# evaluating the limit $ \lim_{x\to \infty} \left( e^{x^2+x}- e^{2x^2+x}\right) $

Tags: limits

$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \left( e^{x^2+x}- e^{2x^2+x}\right) $

I've been trying some manipulation ,

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty}e^{x}\left(e^{x+1}-e^{2x-1}\right) $$
$$ \lim_{x\to \infty}e^{2x}\left(e-\frac{e^{x}}e\right) $$

it might lead to $ {-\infty }$

Is this right ? Is there any method with approximation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not right $$e^x e^{x+1} = e^{2x+1} \neq e^{x^2+x}.$$ However your idea was good, you should write $$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \left( e^{x^2+x}- e^{2x^2+x}\right)=\lim_{x\to +\infty} e^{x^2+x}(1-e^{x^2})=-\infty.$$